# What are low, medium and high traffic websites in terms of visits?

Tags: traffic, scalability

We often read on the internet about big famous website such as Facebook, Google, Yahoo... having hundred of million of unique visitors each month.

But what is the order of magnitude for smaller (or should I say usual) websites ?
Could someone give any example of what is a small, medium and very high traffic with a     range of visit a month for instance.

I would just like to have a scale and be able to categorize website as for now, I don't have any reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the alexa traffic details, should give a rough idea.

As for a scale, in unique hits per day.

- tiny < 100
- small < 300
- medium < 1000
- large < 5000
- huge < 10000
- other > 10000

Comment: You definitely do NOT mean "unique HITS" - more VISITS ;) 300 hits many blogs have from the owner coming 3 times a day.

Comment: So you saying bots spamming your site makes it popular?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there are not any standardized terms regarding the traffic on websites. So this here is only my personal opinion:

Several of our customers have website with less then 10 visits per day. I would consider them as very low traffic websites.

For the rest, I think it is easier to measure it in terms of loaded pages per hour/minutes instead of number of visits. You can then break it down to the number of visitors.

Given the fact that a page loads in less than a second I consider all websites with less than one page load per minute as definitely low traffic websites. Usually websites with less than one page load per second are as well considered as low traffic websites.

If you have more than 50 visitors at the same time on your website it starts to become a medium traffic website. If you have more than 5000 visitors at the same time you are getting into the range of high traffic websites.

Then as well it depends on the number of minutes someone stays at the site, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have a play around on Google Trends for some estimates. For example:

[Stack Overflow, SourceForge, Wikipedia, Facebook](http://trends.google.com/websites?q=stackoverflow.com%2C+sourceforge.net%2C+wikipedia.org%2C+facebook.com&geo=all&date=all&sort=0).

[Stack Overflow vs. Sourceforge](http://trends.google.com/websites?q=stackoverflow.com%2C+sourceforge.net&geo=all&date=all&sort=0).

[Hack a Day vs. Stack Overflow](http://trends.google.com/websites?q=hackaday.com%2C+stackoverflow.com&geo=all&date=all&sort=0).

It's a bit difficult without actual numbers, but for a broad feeling of "how big is X", try comparing against some of those.

Comment: Those trends only tell how often someone searched for those websites. Not how often someone visited those websites.

Comment: @Raffael see http://www.google.com/intl/en/trends/websites/help/index.html#about

Comment: OK. Thanks. I had in mind that they only use the the numbers from the search engine and how many times someone clicks on a link then. In this case they use Google Analytics etc. as well. In this case those numbers are more useful than I thought.